# Node Express path hash anchor

Tags: node.js, express, path, anchor

I currently have the following url structure in my Node application:

```
http://localhost:3000/#record_2
```

Clicking on a link like the above will scroll the webpage to the element with the matching id of **record_2**.

But I need extra information which can be detected and used in my Express path. I have tried the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/#record_2?test=2
http://localhost:3000/#record_2/test/2
```

However, my path is not recognised using the following code :

```
app.get('/#:record/test/:id', async (request, response) => {
    console.log('Request: ', request.params)
    response.redirect('/')
})

app.get('/#:record?test=:id', async (request, response) => {
    console.log('Request: ', request.params)
    response.redirect('/')
})
```

I don't need the **#record_???** segment to be processed on the server. How can I get the **test** part back to my server code for processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path segments and query options must become *before* the hash symbol: `http://localhost:3000/?test=2#record_2` or `http://localhost:3000/test/2/#record_2`.